# Slide/scroll effect when linking to an anchor

Tags: anchor

I have a link at the top of my site, that link to an object in the middle of my site. I have made a anchor link, so the user don´t need to scroll.

But I was wondering if I could make a slide/scroll effect, so when they click on the link, it scroll "slowly" to the object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll To Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Comment: Check this out: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Essentially you need to link your javascript:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then add your script code:

```
    <script>
   $(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
 });
});
 </script>
```